# Интеграция Alfresco c 1C или Диадок

Tags: 1с, интеграция, alfresco

Можно ли интегрировать Alfresco с 1С или Диадок? Если да, то что будет лучше для интеграции? Есть ли публичное API? Буду рад любому мнению.

Answer (score 0):

По Alfresco - не скажу, Диадок - см https://www.diadoc.ru/integrations/1c